# Unable to use ShowInLegend Property along with drawTable in highcharts Piechart

Tags: javascript, python, django, highcharts, jinja2

I was successful in rendering a dataTable within the pie chart div for my Django application. It can be found here:  http://jsfiddle.net/6vqzLo7h/

```js
$(function () {
    
    Highcharts.setOptions({
    colors: [
      '#1cc88a', '#008a59', '#6adfb6'
    ]
  });
    
    Highcharts.drawTable = function() {
     
     // user options
     var tableTop = 200,
         colWidth = 60,
         tableLeft = 50,
         rowHeight = 20,
         cellPadding = 2.5,
         valueDecimals = 1,
         valueSuffix = '';
         
     // internal variables
     var chart = this,
         series = chart.series,
         renderer = chart.renderer,
         cellLeft = tableLeft;

     // draw category labels
     $.each(series, function(serie_index, serie) {
         renderer.text(
             serie.name, 
             cellLeft + cellPadding, 
             tableTop + (serie_index + 1) * rowHeight - cellPadding
         )
         .css({
             fontWeight: 'bold'
         })       
         .add();
     });

    
        
         $.each(series[0].data, function(i) {
            
             renderer.text(
                     series[0].data[i].name, 
                     cellLeft + colWidth - cellPadding, 
                     tableTop + (i + 2) * rowHeight - cellPadding
                 )
                 .attr({
                     align: 'right'
                 })
                 .add();
            });
         $.each(series[0].data, function(i) {
             renderer.text(
                     Highcharts.numberFormat(series[0].data[i].y, valueDecimals) + valueSuffix, 
                     150, 
                     tableTop + (i + 2) * rowHeight - cellPadding
                 )
                 .attr({
                     align: 'left'
                 })
                 .add();
      
         });
         
     
         
 }
    
    
    
    
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            events: {
             load: Highcharts.drawTable
         },
            height: 600,
            width: 800,
         marginBottom: 250
        },
        title: {
            text: undefined
          },
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
         pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
              showInLegend: true,
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                            verticalAlign: 'top',
                            enabled: true,
                            color: '#000000',
                            connectorWidth: 1,
                            distance: -50,
                            connectorColor: '#000000',
                            format: '<br>{point.percentage:.1f} %<br>Count: {point.y}'
                          }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Vulnerability Counts',
            data: [{
                      y: 4,
                      name: 'high',
                    }, {
                      y: 8,
                      name: 'medium',
                    }, {
                      y: 2,
                      name: 'low'
                    }]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

However, I am unable to display a legend box, since **showInLegend:true** is not reflected. It needs to be shown along with the dataTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `showInLegend` feature works fine, but your dimensions settings pushed the legend outside the container.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d36fmcj5/

```
chart: {
  //plotBackgroundColor: null,
  //plotBorderWidth: null,
  //plotShadow: false,
  events: {
    load: Highcharts.drawTable
  },
  height: 400,
  width: 800,
  //marginBottom: 250
},
```